# java, multithreading, how to block another method

Tags: java

I have one class having 2 method, Read method and Write method.
I want multi-thread can get access the read method and only 1 thread get access the read method. And when the write method is accessed, the read method will be blocked. How should I do it?

Note: after reading the answers I wrote a little piece of code for this, I used concurrent package lock.

```
public class ConcurrentLock {
private Lock wLock = new Lock();
private Lock rLock = new Lock();
private int i;
public static void main(String[] args){

}
public int Read(){
    try {
        rLock.lock();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        rLock.unlock();
    }
    return i;
}

public void Write(){
    try {
        wLock.lock();
        rLock.lock();
        ++i;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        wLock.unlock();
        rLock.unlock();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Here you go. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/thread_basics.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [Readers-Writer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock), you can directly in Java 5+ use the [ReadersWriteLock.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) possible implementations to achieve exactly that. You have to acquire and release the appropriate readers and writer locks. See the Javadoc for examples.

Note that even though it is not very clear in your OP, blocking threads that try to read because another is already reading does not make sense and only increases contention. Two readers should be allowed to read concurrently. However, writers should have exclusive access.

Answer (score 1):

the native way ;)

```
public void read() {
      synchronized(readLock) {
           // critical operations like resource.get(Some)
      }
}
public void write() {
      synchronized(writeLock) {
           synchronized(readLock) {
              // critical operations like resource.put(Some, Some)
           }
      }
}

// for the academic

public void onlyOneReaderAndOnlyOneWriter() {
      writeLock = readLock;
}

public void multipleReadersAndOnlyOneWriter() {
     synchronized(readLock) { // grr, tricky
         writeLock = new Object();
     }
}
```

Comment: I definitely understand your logic on this, but could you tell me more details like what should be put into the "writeLock" and "readLock"? I used the object level lock(just used synnchronized key word) and class level lock(synchronized(someclass.class), do you mean that what can put  within synchronized? I am a newbie to Java.

Comment: put your "critical" code inside it, means the operations you want to be synchronized. you do not need any further sync inside. I'll edit the answer to make it more clear..

Answer (score 0):

Mark both of them as synchronized.

Comment: this will block readers against readers and starve readers unnecessarily.